# How does the following Python code snippet work?

Tags: python-2.7

I don't understand the following code in Python

```
l = []
l += [1],[2]
print l # this gives [[1],[2]]
```

However,

```
l = []
l = l + [1],[2]
print l # this gives ([2], [3])
```

Can anyone explain the reason of the above behavior?  I use Python 2.7

Thanks.

Comment: When I try it gives back:  `([1], [2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
l = l + [1],[2]
```

then

```
l+[1]
```

is evaluated first on the right hand side, simplifying the evaluation to

```
l = [1],[2]
```

which is interpreted as a tuple, and a re-assignment of the name "l". In your first expression, the tuple of lists on the right hand side are appended one by one, and the name "l" remains a list.